# Image as background for <div> (UPDATE: PUT MY CSS FILE IN SAME DIRECTORY AS INDEX.html, works great. I dunno....)

Tags: html, css

Trying to use an image as the background of a div.  It just will not show up.  I now have the pic in the same directory as my index.html page.

```
    h1{
 font-family: 'Oldenburg', cursive;
 text-align: center;
}

header{
text-align: center;
}

h2{
font-family: 'Allura', cursive;
text-align: center;
}

 #footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu{
font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
text-align: center;
font-size:  2em;
background-image: url("redone.jpg")
}



 a{
color: black;
}


.main{
height: 500px;
border-style: solid;
background-image: url("images/redone.jpg");
}




<!--  AND    -->

<div class="main">
```

I figure I have the syntax correct, I just have nothing else to try...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check the path of the image, is it in the same location as your html?

Comment: url("./redone.jpg");

Comment: Is your image in RGB mode? If it is in CMYK mode it won't show in the browser. Only guessing here :)

Comment: we may need to see some working example to diagnose your issue. Either a SO snippet or a codepen or something. Otherwise what you are doing is correct

Comment: and I assume you have your css closed properly with an } and have an end </div>.......

Comment: should work. https://jsfiddle.net/0mofq0gj/ Do you have example ?

Comment: Open the dev tools window, is the css being applied under the "computed" tab in the css inspector? if not, you haven't linked your css correctly. If the css is being applied, then hover over the `background-image url` and it will tell you the file path that the css is trying to access the image at.

Comment: Even with that edit theres no problems that i can see: http://codepen.io/nilestanner/pen/QKwGqV

Comment: So you have the same image in two different directories?

Comment: I've been moving it around, trying different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URLs in CSS are *relative to the location of the `.css` file*. For instance if your directory structure looks like:

- /styles/site.css
- /images/redone.jpg
- /somepage.html

If you referencing `images/redone.jpg` in your CSS it will look for `redone.jpg` at `/styles/images/redone.jpg`.

To correctly resolve the URL you could either keep the URL relative and go down a directory before going to `images`:

```
.main{
  height: 500px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-image: url("../images/redone.jpg");
}
```

Or use an absolute URL:

```
.main{
  height: 500px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-image: url("/images/redone.jpg"); /* note the leading slash */
}
```